# Redshift - Find average sales by month

Tags: amazon-redshift, average

I have the below query that find count of sales done by month.

```
select to_char(sale_date,'Mon') as mon,
count (*) as "Sales"
from sales
where to_char(sale_date,'yyyy-mm-dd') between '2018-10-01' and '2018-12-01'
group by 1
```

I am trying to find the average sales done by month. How could I modify the above query to get this output. I am using Redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may query a CTE and take the average:

```
WITH cte AS (
    select to_char(sale_date,'Mon') as mon, count (*) as "Sales"
    from sales
    where to_char(sale_date,'yyyy-mm-dd') between '2018-10-01' and '2018-12-01'
    group by 1
)

SELECT AVG(Sales)
FROM cte;
```

Note that ideally you should be grouping by year and month, because a given month can belong to more than one year.  If you wanted to keep your current query, but include the average over all months, then you could try:

```
select
    to_char(sale_date,'Mon') as mon,
    extract(year from sale_date) as year,
    count (*) as "Sales",
    avg(count(*)) over () "AvgSales"
from sales
where to_char(sale_date,'yyyy-mm-dd') between '2018-10-01' and '2018-12-01'
group by 1, 2;
```

Comment: sorry it int let me select the green tick